# Making call to a contract fails

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

I have my contract deployed to basic-erc20.hash-rush.testnet account. It is just [erc20](https://github.com/near-examples/FT) extended with minting and burnable extensions implementated on rust.

When I try to make a call, for example:

```
near call basic-erc20.hash-rush.testnet inc_allowance '{ "escrow_account_id": "facebook.testnet", "amount": "5" }' --accountId malkevych.testnet
```

I receive the message:

```
Scheduling a call: basic-erc20.hash-rush.testnet.inc_allowance({ "escrow_account_id": "facebook.testnet", "amount": "5" })
Receipt: baKLR7NHbUpSRgAr5GVdKXqkJs7PLKS6azHFz183wkN
        Failure [basic-erc20.hash-rush.testnet]: Error: Smart contract panicked: panicked at &#39;The required attached deposit is 33100000000000000000000, but the given attached deposit is is 0&#39;, src&#x2F;lib.rs:462:13
Error:  GuestPanic [Error]: Smart contract panicked: panicked at &#39;The required attached deposit is 33100000000000000000000, but the given attached deposit is is 0&#39;, src&#x2F;lib.rs:462:13
    at Object.parseRpcError (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/rpc_errors.js:38:19)
    at Account.signAndSendTransaction (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:144:36)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async scheduleFunctionCall (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/commands/call.js:28:34)
    at async Object.handler (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/utils/exit-on-error.js:37:9) {
  type: 'GuestPanic',
  index: 0,
  panic_msg: "panicked at 'The required attached deposit is 33100000000000000000000, but the given attached deposit is is 0', src/lib.rs:462:13"
}
```

So then I found that I can attach gas using **--gas** param. So then I make another tx:

```
near call basic-erc20.hash-rush.testnet inc_allowance '{ "escrow_account_id": "facebook.testnet", "amount": "5" }' --accountId malkevych.testnet --gas 33100000000000000000000
Scheduling a call: basic-erc20.hash-rush.testnet.inc_allowance({ "escrow_account_id": "facebook.testnet", "amount": "5" })
Error:  Error: byte array longer than desired length
    at assert (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js:6:21)
    at BN.toArrayLike (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js:571:5)
    at BN.toArray (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js:556:17)
    at BinaryWriter.write_u64 (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/serialize.js:86:66)
    at serializeField (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/serialize.js:216:41)
    at /Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/serialize.js:262:13
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at serializeStruct (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/serialize.js:261:29)
    at serializeField (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/serialize.js:245:13)
    at serializeStruct (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/serialize.js:271:17)
```

So I tried to decrease the amount of gas:

```
near call basic-erc20.hash-rush.testnet inc_allowance '{ "escrow_account_id": "facebook.testnet", "amount": "5" }' --accountId malkevych.testnet --gas 33100000000000000      
Scheduling a call: basic-erc20.hash-rush.testnet.inc_allowance({ "escrow_account_id": "facebook.testnet", "amount": "5" })
Error:  InvalidTxError: {}
    at Object.parseRpcError (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/rpc_errors.js:38:19)
    at JsonRpcProvider.sendJsonRpc (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/providers/json-rpc-provider.js:146:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Account.signAndSendTransaction (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:115:22)
    at async scheduleFunctionCall (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/commands/call.js:28:34)
    at async Object.handler (/Users/bohdan_malkevych/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/lib/node_modules/near-shell/utils/exit-on-error.js:37:9) {
  type: 'InvalidTxError'
}
```

And again it is not successful.

All default tests are running ok, without any errors. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The original error message you got was:

> The required attached deposit is 33100000000000000000000, but the given attached deposit is is 0

Note that this is coming from the contract itself. You can see [the lines that throw this error](https://github.com/near-examples/FT/blob/b1a760f9dc08738c00d664feae55ad56d10a13cb/contracts/rust/src/lib.rs#L271-L278):

```
assert!(
    required_deposit <= attached_deposit,
    "The required attached deposit is {}, but the given attached deposit is is {}",
    required_deposit,
    attached_deposit,
);
```

When using near-cli, you can add `--help` after a command to see what options you can pass. `near call --help` returns lots of info; the relevant bits here are:

```
near call <contractName> <methodName> [args]

Options:
    ...
    --gas                      Max amount of gas this call can use  [string] [default: "100000000000000"]
    --amount                   Number of tokens to attach  [string] [default: "0"]
```

Have you tried keeping `gas` at the default but setting `--amount` to `33100000000000000000000`? The command would look like:

```
 near call basic-erc20.hash-rush.testnet inc_allowance '{ "escrow_account_id": "facebook.testnet", "amount": "5" }' --accountId malkevych.testnet --amount "33100000000000000000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **depositYocto** worked for me.

You can retry the command like so:

```
near call basic-erc20.hash-rush.testnet inc_allowance '{ "escrow_account_id": "facebook.testnet", "amount": "5" }' --accountId malkevych.testnet --depositYocto "33100000000000000000000"
```